# Android host intent filters on a wildcard

Tags: android, android-intent

Is it possible to use wildcards on the android:host attribute ?

Something like:

```
        android:host="*.site.com"
        android:pathPattern=".*"
        android:pathPrefix="/m/"
        android:scheme="http" />
```

Or even

```
        android:host="*.site.*"
        android:pathPattern=".*"
        android:pathPrefix="/m/"
        android:scheme="http" />
```

Comment: I'm trying to find an answer for this question as well, I'll let you know when I have news.

Answer (score 22):

Yes. After reading the [Android code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/483f3b06ea84440a082e21b68ec2c2e54046f5a6/core/java/android/content/IntentFilter.java) of [IntentFilter.AuthorityEntry.match()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/IntentFilter.AuthorityEntry.html#match(android.net.Uri)), I can see that there is a way to put wildcard on host, but only to match the beginning of host. The rules are these:

- Put * as the first character of the host.
- Write the rest of of the host until the end.

**This will work**:

```
    android:host="*site.com"
    android:pathPattern=".*"
    android:scheme="http" />
```

It will catch links of:

- www.site.com
- site.com
- mail.site.com

On the other hand the one below **won't work**:

```
    android:host="*.site.*"
    android:pathPattern=".*"
    android:scheme="http" />
```

Comment: Won't this also catch othersite.com ?

Comment: Yes, but if you want to catch "site.com" this is what you need to do.

Comment: The docs here say that `*.site.com` should work though - "Alternatively, if you declare your hostname with a wildcard (such as *.example.com), you must publish your assetlinks.json file at the root hostname"

Comment: What do you exactly mean by root  hostname? @Noitidart I am trying to achieve app linking for 3 diff work env, alpha.xxx.com, beta.xxx.com, gamma.xxx.com, and prod is xxx.com. I want only one entry in my intent filter for these? shall i use *.xxx.com or *xxx.com? I am using same keystore for debug in all variants, how do I generate one common assetlinks json file for all the env?

Comment: @Kannan_SJD im not sure now, its been awhile and I forgot. :(

Comment: No worries.. Will figure it out.. :) thanks @Noitidart

Comment: Please share @Kannan_SJD when you do!

Comment: Sure @Noitidart

Comment: here is a link to the source code: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/483f3b06ea84440a082e21b68ec2c2e54046f5a6/core/java/android/content/IntentFilter.java please look at line 674 for the match() function

Comment: Thanks @UrielFrankel.. I have checked the source code and understood if the 0th char is * they substring to find the root host.. But for some reason if I user wildcards the applink doesnt work.. Will check and update